# Concatenate variable in Hugo

Tags: hugo

This snippet works wonderfully on Hugo:

```
   {{ if and (or .IsPage .IsSection) .Site.Params.contentCommitsURL }}
                  {{ $File := .File }}
                  {{ $Site := .Site }}
                  {{with $File.Path }}
                  <a href="{{ $Site.Params.contentCommitsURL }}{{ replace $File.Dir "\\" "/" }}{{ $File.LogicalName }}" target="blank">Link to API call</a>
                  {{ end }}
                {{ end }}
```

> With,
>
> ```
> [Params]
> contentCommitsURL = https://api.github.com/repos/csitauthority/CSITauthority.github.io/commits?path=HUGO/content/
> ```
>
> it is able to beautifully generate the following link
>
> [Link to API call](https://api.github.com/repos/csitauthority/CSITauthority.github.io/commits?path=HUGO/content/post/vlan-101.md)
>
> in the `layout` html file.

---

## Problem Description

The URL is generated. Now I'm pulling hairs trying to figure out how to concatenate the commands `{ $Site.Params.contentCommitsURL }}{{ replace $File.Dir "\\" "/" }}{{ $File.LogicalName }}` in a page variable such as `{{ $url }}`

For instance:

```
{{ $url := {{ $Site.Params.contentCommitsURL }}{{ replace $File.Dir "\\" "/" }}{{ $File.LogicalName }} }}
```

does not work

but the following does:

```
{{ $url := "https://api.github.com/repos/csitauthority/CSITauthority.github.io/commits?path=HUGO/content/post/vlan-101.md"}}
```

> ## I want to be able to do something like this:
>
> ```
> {{ $url := $Site.Params.contentCommitsURL + (replace $File.Dir "\\" "/") + $File.LogicalName }}
> ```

^Obviously, that doesn't work. I want to know what does.

Answer (score 1):

On the Hugo discourse forum, someone [hinted a solution](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/concatenate-variable-in-hugo/8819/2?u=siddhantrimal) and I was able to come up with the following.

```
{{ if and (or .IsPage .IsSection) .Site.Params.contentCommitsURL }}
      {{ $File := .File }}
      {{ $Site := .Site }}
      {{with $File.Path }}
      {{ $fileDir := replace $File.Dir "\\" "/"}}
        {{ $url := $File.LogicalName | printf "%s%s" $fileDir | printf "%s%s" $Site.Params.contentCommitsURL }}
        {{ $.Scratch.Set "url" $url }}
      {{ end }}
    {{ end }}
```

Where I want it to appear, I use the `Scratch` function like this:

```
{{ $url := $.Scratch.Get "url"}}
  {{ range getJSON $url }}
    <div style="display:inline-block; width:40px;"><a href="{{.author.html_url}}" target="_blank">
    <img src="{{.author.avatar_url}}" alt="{{.author.login}}" text="{{.author.login}}" class="inline" width="40" height="40" style="height: 40px;height: 40px; vertical-align:middle; margin: 0 auto;"></a>
  </div>
  {{ end }}
```

The code is self-explanatory so I won't bother with a verbose description. Instead, I'd like to bring your focus on the implementation. You'll notice that the `Scratch` function has been used.

The hugo documentation says this:

> Variables defined inside if conditionals and similar are not visible on the outside.
>
> [(see this issue)](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10608)

It's a workaround that involves storing the value temporarily. [here's more on scratch](https://gohugo.io/functions/scratch)

## Limitations

As of this moment, I feel this code is not complete. It works but, it shows the author based on commits. So multiple commits will generate the same author multiple times. I bring this limitation to your notice, to develop a creative solution. I'll update this answer when I get a satisfactory answer. Meanwhile, feel free to suggest.

[here](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/concatenate-variable-in-hugo/8819/3?u=siddhantrimal)'s my original answer on hugo discourse.

Answer (score 0):

You can join them in these ways:

1 args

```
{{ $variable := printf "%s" $args_1st_in_string | printf "%s" }}
```

2 args

```
{{ $variable := printf "%s" $args_1st_in_string | printf "%s%s" $args_2nd_in_string | printf "%s" }}
```

multiple args

```
{{ $variable := printf "%s" $args_1st_in_string | ..... | printf "%s%s" $args_last_args_in_string | printf "%s" }}
```